# Does Window for Galileo support .NET language?

Tags: intel-galileo, windowsondevices

I'm finding more information about **Window version for Galileo** because i have very little information on internet. 
According to this information from pcworld, i found that this board is very interesting because i'm a big fan of Window : http://www.pcworld.com/article/2691252/microsofts-custom-windows-os-now-on-galileo-gen2-board.html

> Microsoft’s stripped-down version of Windows 8 is coming to the Intel
>   Galileo Gen2 developer board.

- I was imagined that the advantage of Window is that i can coding on rapid development language like VB.NET or C#. But I see all sample from github is all in C++. So can i using VB.NET or C# as well instead of C++ ? Any sample for vb.net or c# ?

Comment: I think you're seriously misinterpreting what they are actually offering: sure, the OS is called Windows 8, but it's text-only and judging by the startup time of 2 minutes, slow as molasses on that 400MHz singlecore.  See http://ms-iot.github.io/content/SetupGalileo.htm .  Such a device certainly *has* it's applications, but I think you're expecting a small, somewhat limited version of your desktop machine.  It's not.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, according to this information from Microsoft : http://ms-iot.github.io/content/WelcomeAndFAQ.htm

> Q: Will you support C#/WinRT/.NET/Node/JS… ? A: For this first preview
>   release, we’re focusing on C++ and Arduino compatibility. In future
>   iterations, our intent is to support the Universal App model announced
>   at Build.

I have heard some blog post from internet say that they succeed to run a .NET application on Window Iot. That's very excited and promise future. Put my hope on that!

Answer (score 0):

An effort is underway to [port Mono over to the Galileo](http://jeremiahmorrill.wordpress.com/2014/09/05/mono-on-windows-for-intel-galileo-source-code/).   It's in early development, so you probably won't want to base any projects on it yet.

If you are interested in coding in VB.NET or C# on an embedded platform, your best bet right now is the [.Net Micro Framework (aka Gadgeteer)](http://www.netmf.com/gadgeteer/).  It doesn't run on Galileo, but the hardware which does support it is comparable.  It has been around for many years and is quite stable.  It was open-sourced then neglected by Microsoft for the past few years, but there are signs that Microsoft has taken a renewed interest in it, including a shout-out in the Galileo FAQ.